# Downgrade to Win7 from Win8(Pro)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, laptop, drivers, downgrade

I've just bought new laptop, it's an HP Pavilion 17-e072nr.
But it turned out it was a refurbished one, at least not an untouched one.
But it is unused, plastic films still on it, smells new etc.
The shop says it is delivered with Windows 8, but it is not clear wether Win8, Win 8.1, or Win8.1 Pro is installed. I think it is at least a Pro version of one of them because it has 8GB RAM. There is no disc sent along with the laptop.

This doesn't really bother me but the fact is, I really, really don't like Win8 at all and i would do anything for being able to downgrade it to Win7. I can't get used to Win8.
And you would be able to do so without much trouble if you have Win8Pro. 
I haven't touched the laptop yet for warranty/returning reasons, and maybe it is better to install Win7 before waking Win8, I don't know.

I couldn't find a clear guide to downgrade to Win7, and if there are any,(I would be grateful if anyone could refer me to it) I still cope with the problem that my type of notebook originally wasn't available in my country. Maybe it is even some kind of protoype, I can't find any information about it on the web.
So I can't find the drivers either, and I suppose I need those for Win7 to function properly on my device. I'm a dutch so maybe that clears up something.

**Long story short:** I have a Win8 device which I want to downgrade to Win7, but it is a quite unfindable type so I can't find any information and drivers for it.
I'm getting kind of desperate so any help would be really appreciated!
If there's a post that answers this queastion, or a clear guide how to downgrade, i would be thankful if you could refer met oe it because i couln't find it.

Comment: Call the manufacturer (HP) for some assistance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have an OEM version of Windows, so you should be eligible to downgrade to Windows 7 Pro.

You should contact HP and request the installation media and product key. The program is detailed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2832566) (note that it states the OEM (HP) is not obligated to give you the installation media, so you may have to obtain this on your own).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to downgrade directly from windows 8 to windows 7, no.

The only way to do what you want to do in this case is to get an OEM copy of Windows 7 and install it fresh, copying your drivers from 8 onto a flash drive and installing them during the windows 7 OEM install. To my knowledge, Microsoft distributes a software that automates the driver backup, and any windows 7 OEM install should have the option to install the drivers from this backup.

May I say, though, that downgrading to windows 7 may not be a good option as soon enough 7 will be unsupported. Some software being distributed already requires a minimum operating system of windows 8.

Comment: Actually it is possible...an OEM copy of Windows 7 would require an OEM Windows 7 license